# My code is not working properly

Tags: selenium, java, code-review

I am working in selenium web driver. I am using selenium 3.0 jar files and firefox version is 49. I am getting a error message. Can anybody tell me the solution ?

```
package Hello;



import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class first {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/naveen/geckodriver");
         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.get("http://54.68.159.204/qmsadm");
            WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
            ele.sendKeys("");
            ele=driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
            ele.sendKeys("");

            ele.submit();




            System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

> Console : Oct 07, 2016 2:25:04 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the
>   remote end 1475830505565  Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 42877
>   1475830508698 Marionette  INFO    startBrowser
>   cd9def2c-de8e-4868-83c6-696d073993b6 Oct 07, 2016 2:25:09 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: W3C
>
> (firefox:4893): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static:
>   assertion 'g_type_parent (interface_type) == G_TYPE_INTERFACE' failed
>
> (firefox:4893): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static:
>   assertion 'g_type_parent (interface_type) == G_TYPE_INTERFACE' failed
>
> (firefox:4893): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static:
>   assertion 'g_type_parent (interface_type) == G_TYPE_INTERFACE' failed
>
> (firefox:4893): GLib-GObject-WARNING **:
>   /build/glib2.0-7IO_Yw/glib2.0-2.48.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3486: signal
>   name 'selection_changed' is invalid for instance '0x7f970701a650' of
>   type 'MaiAtkType139'
>
> (firefox:4893): GLib-GObject-WARNING **:
>   /build/glib2.0-7IO_Yw/glib2.0-2.48.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3486: signal
>   name 'selection_changed' is invalid for instance '0x7f970701a880' of
>   type 'MaiAtkType139'

Comment: Thankyou. Updating selenium version to latest solved the above problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download latest version of selenium jar files and try it. I tried the same code in my system and it worked fine

Comment: Very strange - any idea what about the versioning might have been off?